# MathJax rendering when browsing next pages of the list of my own answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

While using Firefox 19.0 and navigating to the listing of my own answers the MathJax renders fine on the [first page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11069/sasha?tab=answers), but does not render when transitioning to the [second page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11069/sasha?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=2). The only way to force it to render is to refresh the page.

Please consider fixing this. It is a long time behavior and it gets in the way of efficiently using this site, at least for me.

Comment: It'd be great if this would be fixed. For reference [here's my post from June 2011 about it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2315/264).

Comment: Until this bug is fixed, the [ChatJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3297/4583) bookmarklet is a workaround. You'll only need to click it once when you load your answers page. $\LaTeX$ will be automatically rendered when you switch pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. Your work is much appreciated.

Comment: Huzzah!${}{}{}{}$